# Google sheets: summing cells in a column where the cell above contains a string

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to sum the cells in a column where the cell above contains a string. For example, sum all the cells where the cell directly above contains the string "Transport".

For example, in the following (which I have just inserted the correct numbers into), the 'Total transport' cell contains 42 as it is the sum of 10 + 20 + 12, from those cells with the string 'Transport' above them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use do it in several steps :

- check if condition is met
- set value accordingly
- sum all

Using  `=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

[image]

`=IF(A1="hello", A2,0)` - this will set the values in the B column according the existence of a string.
Than you can use `=SUM(B2:B12)`.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Though I felt, OP has some numbers is those cells and OP wants the summation of those numbers, only if the cell (which contains the number) lies below a cell (which contains the string).

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify.